# SQL Server use SCOPE_IDENTITY() for insert into with select command

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hello I have one table whose name is

```
PERSO_DATA(Id,refPerso,,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5)
```

and I have

```
PERSO_DATA_QUEUE(Id,refPersoData,refVideo)
```

Firstly I will insert to datas to `PERSO_DATA` then I will take Id of inserted data and isnsert to another table as refPersoData.

```
INSERT INTO PERSO_DATA(refPerso,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5)
        SELECT @refPerso,pa.Col1,pa.Col2,pa.Col3,pa.Col4,pa.Col5 FROM #PERSODATA pa
    SET @refPersoData=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

When I write like that i insert all datas but can't take the Id for each data

```
INSERT INTO PERSO_DATA_QUEUE(refVideoQueue,refPersoData)
        SELECT @refVideoQueue,@refPersoData
```

so code above it add only one.But I want if I have 10 data to insert `PERSO_DATA` I need to also insert `PERSO_DATA_QUEUE` table 10 data with inserted Ids.

How can I do this? I couldn't find a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need a cursor for this

Comment: You can use an `OUTPUT` clause of the `INSERT` statement to handle multi-row inserts. The virtual inserted table will contain the assigned identity values so you don't need to use SCOPE_IDENTITY(). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql

Comment: Write `Insert Trigger` on PERSO_DATA table.

Comment: How do you know which `refVideoQueue` goes with which `refPersoData` in `PERSO_DATA_QUEUE`?

Comment: To add to Dan Guzman's comment: You can use an [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to get any data from the rows (Note plural.), e.g. identity column values for newly inserted rows. `OUTPUT` can be used with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `MERGE` and provides access to both _before_ and _after_ values in the case of `UPDATE`. A tool well worth having in your pocket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp ([Id] [bigint] NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO PERSO_DATA(refPerso,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.Id
    INTO #temp (Id)
    SELECT @refPerso,pa.Col1,pa.Col2,pa.Col3,pa.Col4,pa.Col5 
        FROM #PERSODATA pa;

INSERT INTO PERSO_DATA_QUEUE(refVideoQueue,refPersoData)
    SELECT @refVideoQueue, Id
        FROM #temp;
```

Comment: This answer is actually what I want. Thanks

Comment: @Çağrı, glad to help you

Answer (score -1):

The solution might be combining either cursor or loop and any iterator - like ROW_NUMBER() in your temp table. 
Then - use SCOPE_IDENTITY() in it to get created IDENTITY value.

Comment: No a loop is not the best way to handle this. You should instead use the OUTPUT clause. Regardless this isn't an answer as it is a vague guess.

Comment: I have never said it is the best way, since cursor are always not the best solution. That's one of the ways that can be used.

Comment: they almost never are the best solution.

Comment: But you posted a suggestion using a cursor as an answer. I would repose not to comment that your suggestion is not a good one. A cursor here is just the wrong way go about this.